# Вывод массива laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Мне нужно выводить массив категорий.
Вот что у меня в IndexController

```
public function __invoke()
    {
        $servers = Server::take(3)->get();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('main.index', compact('servers','categories'));
    }
```

Вот что у моей модели

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'server_categories', 'server_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

У меня в БД таблица`server`строка`category_id` подкреплена к другой таблице `server_categories`
Вот что у меня в migrate `server`

```
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();

            $table->index('category_id','server_category_idx');
            $table->foreign('category_id','server_category_fk')->on('categories')->references('id');
```

Вот что у меня в migrate `server_categories`

```
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('server_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

            $table->index('server_id','server_category_server_idx');
            $table->index('category_id','server_category_category_idx');

            $table->foreign('server_id','server_category_server_fk')->on('servers')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('category_id','server_category_category_fk')->on('categories')->references('id');
```

Вот что у меня в index.blade.php

```
@foreach($servers as $server)

@dd($server->categories['title'])

@endforeach
```

И выводится следующая ошибка `Undefined index: title`

Я не понимаю в чем проблема, ведь раньше другие массивы я выводил именно так

Вот что у меня выводится когда я пишу

```
@dd($server->categories)
```

[image: Вывод массива]

Если я что-то забыл вам показать, напиши. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin дак у меня все в виде текста, только скрин, что мне щас все с скрина копировать

Comment: с картинки перенабирать текст, конечно, не нужно. лучше было вместо снимка экрана выделить-скопировать-вставить текст. если, конечно, интерфейс вашей операционной системы позволяет это сделать в данном случае.

Comment: Ты не думал о том, что у сервера много категорий? `$server->categories` - это коллекция же, а не отдельная категория. Вот он и рукается на то, что ты от коллекции пытаешься получить элемент по ключу `title`

Comment: @МаксимК Да, это коллекция категорий, подскажи как ее вывести )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас отношение многие-ко-многим, поэтому каждому серверу принадлежит несколько категорий. Для их вывода создайте вложенный цикл:

```
@foreach($servers as $server)
    @foreach($server->categories as $category)
        {{$category->title}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: спасибо) вы мне помогли